# .htaccess password protection for specific domain

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Is there a way to require a htaccess login only for a specific domain?
I'm using Drupal and it is set up as a multisite installation but only one site is supposed to be protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the Secure Site module: http://drupal.org/project/securesite

It allows you to protect a site using HTTP basic authorization. The usernames and passwords will be from the Drupal users table, rather than a separate htpassword file.

In Apache configuration (either htaccess or httpd.conf) the AuthType is always tied to the directory.  I don't think you can tie the authorization to named virtual host just with Apache configuration.